# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= (even though i'm using IN clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   headcount 
WHERE  [mso/bu2] = @MSOBU 
       AND [status] = 'billable' 
       AND [location type] = 'offshore' 
       AND [vertical group] = @Vertical 
       AND lob IN( CASE 
                     WHEN @LOB = 'dgtl' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT lob 
                                              FROM   lob 
                                              WHERE  category = 'esg') 
                     WHEN @LOB = 'nondgtl' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT lob 
                                                 FROM   lob 
                                                 WHERE  category <> 'esg') 
                     WHEN @LOB = '' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT lob 
                                          FROM   headcount) 
                   END )
```

i'm stuck in this error even though i'm using IN clause

Comment: Instead of Distinct Try Top 1

Comment: No i cant because that column has more than one value

Comment: The THEN clauses may not return more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   headcount 
WHERE  [mso/bu2] = @MSOBU 
       AND [status] = 'billable' 
       AND [location type] = 'offshore' 
       AND [vertical group] = @Vertical 
       AND ( ( @LOB = 'dgtl' 
               AND lob IN (SELECT DISTINCT lob 
                           FROM   lob 
                           WHERE  category = 'esg') ) 
              OR ( @LOB = 'nondgtl' 
                   AND lob IN (SELECT DISTINCT lob 
                               FROM   lob 
                               WHERE  category <> 'esg') ) 
              OR  @LOB = '') )
```

Comment: yes, i wish to but i have got only 3 reputaions.. my bad.. but i will mark this as  answer ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Operand of CASE WHEN *must by* one value, not a many rows.

Try to rewrite query like that:

```
 select COUNT(*) 
   from HeadCount
  where [MSO/BU2]=@MSOBU and [Status]='billable'
    and [Location Type]='offshore' and [Vertical Group]= @Vertical
    and (@LOB=''
          OR 
         LOB in(
         select distinct lob from LOB
          where (@LOB='dgtl'    and Category ='esg') OR
                (@LOB='nondgtl' and Category<>'esg')
               )
        )
```

For `@LOB=''` no subquery need as it select all rows of main table (HeadCount).